# Excel VBA IF AND Statement

Tags: excel, vba, if-statement, commandbutton

in my excel file i would like to have a commandbutton which send an email to all persons in column A if in column B value is no.

Now my problem is that i am not able to write the If-And statement correct.

This part of my code is wrong:

```
If cell.Value Like "?*.?*@?*.?*" And LCase(Cells(cell.Row, "B").Value) = "no" Then
```

If i delete the **And** statement the button works fine.

I hope someone can help me to solve this problem.

Many Thanks

**EDIT**

I could solve my problem :)

Code has to look like this:

```
If cell.Value Like "?*.?*@?*.?*" And _
LCase(Cells(cell.Row, "BD").Value) = "No" Then
```

Comment: LCase(Cells(cell.Row, "BD").Value) **will never equal** "No"

Comment: ^^ That and  LCase$ will be more efficient

Comment: And "BD" is not the same as "B".

Comment: I think the cells() is looking for the column to be referenced as an integer/number instead of `B`. Try `If cell.Value Like "?*.?*@?*.?*" And LCase(Cells(cell.Row,2).Value) = "no" Then`